# Logic Algebra - Simplification

Tags: logic

I have come up with the following equation to solve a problem:

(A ∨ C ∨ D) ∧ (¬ D → B) ∧ ( ¬ C → (A ⊕ D)) ∧  ¬ (E ∧ (A ∨ B)) ∧ ¬ ( ¬ B → ( ¬ A ∨ ¬ C))

According to Wolfram Alpha, the correct result is: A ∧ ¬ B ∧ C ∧ D ∧ ¬ E = true;

While the truth table is perfectly suitable to check for errors, I am not supposed to use truth tables to get the result but simplifications.

My problem is that I have failed to get the correct result.

Here is what I got:

(A ∨ C ∨ D) ∧ (D ∨ B) ∧ (C ∨((A ∨ D) ∧ ¬ (A ∧ D))) ∧ (¬ E ∨ (¬ A ∧ ¬ B)) ∧ ¬ (B ∨ (¬ A ∨ ¬ C)) ⇔

(A ∨ C ∨ D) ∧ (D ∨ B) ∧ (C ∨((A ∨ D) ∧ (¬ A ∨ ¬ D))) ∧ (¬ E ∨ (¬ A ∧ ¬ B)) ∧ (¬ B ∧ (A ∧ C)) ⇔

(A ∨ C ∨ D) ∧ (D ∨ B) ∧ (C ∨((A ∨ D) ∧ (¬ A ∨ ¬ D))) ∧ (¬ E ∨ (¬ A ∧ ¬ B)) ∧ ¬ B ∧ A ∧ C ⇔

(A ∨ C ∨ D) ∧ A ∧ (D ∨ B) ¬ B  ∧ (C ∨((A ∨ D) ∧ (¬ A ∨ ¬ D))) ∧ (¬ E ∨ (¬ A ∧ ¬ B)) ∧ C ⇔

((A ∧ A) ∨ (A ∧ C) ∨ (A ∧ D)) ∧ ((D ∧ ¬ B) ∨ (B ∧ ¬ B)) ∧ (C ∨((A ∨ D) ∧ (¬ A ∨ ¬ D))) ∧ (¬ E ∨ (¬ A ∧ ¬ B)) ∧ C ⇔

(A ∨ (A ∧ C) ∨ (A ∧ D)) ∧ ((D ∧ ¬ B) ∨ false) ∧ (C ∨((A ∨ D) ∧ (¬ A ∨ ¬ D))) ∧ (¬ E ∨ (¬ A ∧ ¬ B)) ∧ C ⇔

(A ∨ (A ∧ (C ∨ D)) ∧ (D ∧ ¬ B) ∧ (C ∨((A ∨ D) ∧ (¬ A ∨ ¬ D))) ∧ (¬ E ∨ (¬ A ∧ ¬ B)) ∧ C ⇔

(A ∨ (A ∧ (C ∨ D))) ∧ (D ∧ ¬ B) ∧ (C ∨((A ∨ D) ∧ (¬ A ∨ ¬ D))) ∧ (¬ E ∨ (¬ A ∧ ¬ B)) ∧ C ⇔

A ∧ (D ∧ ¬ B) ∧ (C ∨((A ∨ D) ∧ (¬ A ∨ ¬ D))) ∧ (¬ E ∨ (¬ A ∧ ¬ B)) ∧ C ⇔

A ∧ (D ∧ ¬ B) ∧ ∧ C  (C ∨((A ∨ D) ∧ (¬ A ∨ ¬ D))) ∧ (¬ E ∨ (¬ A ∧ ¬ B)) ⇔

A ∧ (D ∧ ¬ B) ∧ ((C ∧ C) ∨ (C ∧ ((A ∨ D) ∧ (¬ A ∨ ¬ D)))) ∧ (¬ E ∨ (¬ A ∧ ¬ B)) ⇔

A ∧ (D ∧ ¬ B) ∧ (C ∨ (C ∧ ((A ∨ D) ∧ (¬ A ∨ ¬ D)))) ∧ (¬ E ∨ (¬ A ∧ ¬ B)) ⇔

A ∧ (D ∧ ¬ B) ∧ C ∧ (¬ E ∨ (¬ A ∧ ¬ B)) ⇔

UPDATE 1:
added a missing ¬

UPDATE 2:
!!! PLEASE DO NOT BOTHER TO ANSWER!!!
I have finally managed to figure it out and will add my new calculations as an answer later this day.